# Internet explorer Compatibility with css3 and HTML5

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer

I've noticed that Windows 7 comes with internet explorer 8, which does not support HTML5 or CSS3. Windows 8 comes with an with Internet Explorer 11, which does support HTML5 and CSS3

I'm developing a C# application that uses web page interfaces using HTML5 & CSS3 in a web browser control. The problem is that Internet Explorer 8 does not supporting it.

I used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

in my web pages. Also, I used the alternative DWORD value in Regedit with the value 9000

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
```

If Internet Explorer 9 or above is installed it will be compatible, but I can't install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows XP so my app will not be recommended on XP.

Is there an alternative to the Web Browser Control that Supports HTML5, CSS3 and Events Handlers? If not how to install Internet Explorer 9 and above on Windows XP?

Comment: embed chrome or firefox direct into your application or search for a port of the webkit engine for C# there are some of them

Comment: I'm so frustrated. it's my graduation project. -1 makes the others do that :(

Comment: the interfaces are interactive with users, I not sure if chrome or Firefox have an events handlers!

Comment: then what about the webkit ports. inb4 these need work to get them working as you like

Comment: I'll google for webkit ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you block your application on machines that don't have the required version of IE installed, by using this method to check the installed version...

```
internal static bool GetIsCompatibleIEVersionInstalled(int minimumRequiredVersion)
{
    var compatibleIEVersionInstalled = false;

    var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer");

    var fullVersion = (string)key.GetValue("Version");

    int majorVersion;

    if (int.TryParse(fullVersion.Split('.').First(), out majorVersion))
    {
        compatibleIEVersionInstalled = majorVersion >= minimumRequiredVersion;
    }

    return compatibleIEVersionInstalled;
}
```

Comment: thanks, if internet explorer 9 installed or above, it will be Compatible :)
but i can't install internet explorer 9 on win XP so my app will not be recommended on xp :( that is my issue bro

Comment: Do you know what percentage of your users will be running Windows XP?

Comment: maybe 10% but I'm obsessed making apps run in any windows platform :)

Comment: Why do we escape from XP :) ?